# Solving $\cos(x)\cos(2x) = \cos(3x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Are there specific trigonometric identities that I can use to solve the following problem:
\begin{align*}
\cos(x)\cos(2x) = \cos(3x)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**
\begin{align*}
\cos(3x) = \cos(x + 2x) = \cos(x)\cos(2x) - \sin(x)\sin(2x)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. Then, I just get -sin(_x_) sin(_2x_) = 0. Can you help me solve the problem from there?

Comment: Sure. Just remember that
\begin{align*}
\sin(\alpha) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \alpha = k\pi
\end{align*}
where $k\in\textbf{Z}$, then solve for $x$ and $2x$.

Comment: If you think I deserve it, give me an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)=\frac{1}{2}[\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)]$$

Apply that result to the LHS, as well as rewrite $\cos(3x)$ as $\cos(2x+x)$ and apply the above result.